# How to post documents and change the schedule in Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: azure-devops

How to post documents and change the schedule of a sprint in Visual Studio Team Services?

Comment: What do you mean about post documents?

Comment: Can you post documents with a project in VSTS?  Or, do I have to use SharePoint?

Comment: You have to use SharePoint

Answer (score -1):

To change the schedule of a sprint, please following the steps below:

1. Open your project from web portal.
2. Click "Project Settings" button in the upper right corner.
3. Open "Work" panel.
4. Click "Set dates" link on the sprint you'd like to change.
   [image]

Comment: Thank you..  This has been answered.

Comment: @PaulByrum What do you mean?